# Check whether asp:fileupload is empty, client side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a fileupload control inside a formview. I would like it to cause a validation error in case no file was uploaded. Can I apply some kind of validator on that or have the control throw the validation error itself?

Comment: have you tried required field validator..?

Comment: @sravan Hrm... I was sure it didn't work when I tried it before but now it's working perfect. I should remove the question I guess... Thanks!

Comment: it works..check out the answer i posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="your own error message" 
    ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

To check file upload has file or not ,use jquery like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').click(function(){
          if($('#uploadFile').val()=="")
           {
           alert("no file selected!");
           return false;
          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Where should I place this code? (never used jquery before...)

Comment: use this code in script block <script type="text/javascript">CODE</code>  learn more about jquery http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: This code not validate file is uploaded. This validate file is selected.

Comment: code will check if there is a file in "file upload" control in javascript as Urik ask for client side validation

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi You can't upload a file anyway if the fileupload control doesn't have a filepath (file) to the file in question.

Comment: You said if file is uploaded. not said if is "has file"

Comment: You are right, he did say that. But you can't upload a file if the control doesn't 'have a file' to upload (e.g. the filepath in the control), so this would still cause the validation to fail. How is this a difficult concept to grasp?

Comment: Also, If you have a file, is not meaning it is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fu1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Click" 
       OnClientClick="return ValidateFileName();" /> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateFileName() {
    var fu = document.getElementById("<%= fu1.ClientID %>");
    var f = fu.value + "";
    if ((f.indexOf("#", 0) >= 0) || (f.indexOf("$", 0) >= 0) ||
          (f.indexOf("%", 0) >= 0) || (f.indexOf("^", 0) >= 0)) {
        alert("Filename: [" + f + "] contains invalid char");
        return false;//will stop button click event here
    }

    return true;
}
```